# Is it safe to concatenate formatted strings using sprintf()?

Tags: c, string, visual-c++, string-concatenation, c-strings

I am writing a program that requires a gradual building of a formatted string, to be printed out as the last stage. The string includes numbers that are collected while the string is formed. Thus, I need to add formatted string fragments to the output string.

One straight forward way is to use `sprintf()` to a temporary string that contains the formatted fragment, which is then concatenated to the output string using `strcat()`, like demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024251/274579).

A more sophisticated approach is to point `sprintf()` to the end of the current output string, when adding the new fragment. This is demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14023067/274579).

The help page to the [MSVC `sprintf_s()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28stdio%2Fsprintf_s%29%3Bk%28sprintf_s%29%3Bk%28DevLang-C%2B%2B%29%3Bk%28TargetOS-Windows%29&rd=true) (and the other variants of `sprintf()`) states that:

> If copying occurs between strings that overlap, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Now, technically, using `sprintf()` to concatenate the fragment to the end of the output string means overwriting the terminating `NULL`, which is considered a part of the first string. So, this action falls under the category of overlapping strings. The technique seems to work well, but is it really safe?

Comment: Once some behaviour is said to be undefined, you are not allowed to assume anything about it. Because it might work today, but tomorrow the behaviour will change without a notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method in the answer you linked to:

> [strcat() for formatted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023024/strcat-for-formatted-strings/14023067#14023067)

is safe against overlapping string issues, but of course it's unsafe in that it's performing unbounded writes using `sprintf` rather than `snprintf`.

What's not safe, and what the text about overlapping strings is referring to, is something like:

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s%s", buf, tail);
```

Here, overlapping ranges of `buf` are being used both as an input and an output, and this results in undefined behavior. Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks. There are a few examples in SO for upvoted answers which give a variation on the `sprintf()` method, and I saw no objections. Hence my question. So, are you suggesting that this method is NOT safe after all and should be avoided (where it does work in particular implementations, but to be considered non portable)? If so, it may be worth to comment on the other answers.

Comment: I re-read your answer. So, basically, you talk about the same method, with the difference in using the `sizeof` operator. Is this because the *order of evaluation* is undefined?

Comment: That makes sense, actually. But then, why would the 1st form be considered safe, where the quote from MSDN prohibits overlapping strings

Comment: @ysap: In the linked answer, none of the `sprintf` calls write into any of the buffers they're reading from. So there is simply no overlap. I think you're mistakenly reading overlap as being about writing to the same buffer from *multiple `sprintf` calls*. This is not what it's about and of course there is no restriction on that.

Comment: As I noted in the answer, however, even without the overlapping strings problem, the linked answer is not good because it's using `sprintf`, and `sprintf` (without the n) is basically always a bug, because it's hard to ensure that it will not write past the end of the buffer.

Comment: Woooo.... I think you're right and I misinterpreted the documentation. No I do not read overlap as multiple writing, it is just a momentary lapse of attention.